# how to reuse stdout output without saving it to physical disk file

Tags: ksh

I have a for-loop, like the following:

```
for inf from $filelist; do
  for ((i=0; i<imax; ++i)); do
    temp=`<command_1> $inf | <command_2>`
    eval set -A array -- $temp
    ...
  done 
  ...
done
```

Problem is, `command_1` a bit time consuming and its output is a bit large (900MB is the highest, depending on how big the input file is). So, I modified the script to:

```
outf="./temp"
for inf from $filelist; do
  <command_1> $inf -o $outf
  for ((i=0; i<imax; ++i)); do
    temp=`cat $outf | <command_2>`
    eval set -A array -- $temp
    ...
  done 
  ...
done
```

There is a little performance improvement, but not so much as I want, probably because disk I/O is a performance bottle-neck as well.

Just curious if there is a way to save the `stdout` output of `command_1`, so that I could reuse it without saving it to a physical disk file?

Comment: This really depends on how much data *command_2* produces, and how much it needs from *command_1*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### don't use pipelines inside nested loops

Based on new comments and another look at the original question, I would strongly recommend *against* using a pipeline processing large amounts of data *inside* a nested loop.  Shell pipelines are far from efficient, and incur lots of process overhead.

Look at the original problem, this involves looking into the contributions of `command_1` and `command_2`, and see if you could solve this in another way.

That said: here's the original answer:

In the shell there are two ways of storing data: either in a shell variable, or in a file.  You *might*  try to store that file in a memory based filesystem, like /dev/shm on linux or tmpfs in Solaris.

You might also analyse `command_1` and `command_2` for optimisations.  Is there anything in the output of `command_1` that's not needed by `command_2`?  Try to put a filter between the two.

Example:

```
command_1 | awk '{ print $2 }' | command_2
```

(Assuming `command_2` only needs column 2 of `command_1`'s output.)

Comment: Good idea, Henk! Yes, in each loop iteration, only the i-th column is needed. But how to embedded this `awk` statement into the for-loop? I tried `command_1 | awk '{ print $$i }' | command_2` (in a for-loop), but it doesn't work. Any suggestions here?

Comment: Try `... | awk -v i=$i '{ print $i }' | ...`  or `... | cut -f$i | ...`.   However, it looks like you could use a solution based on pure awk/perl/python/..., without all the process overhead.